Encryption & Decryption with RSA_PKCS1_PADDING algorithm in Express js
I am using express js. Encryption and decryption completely works in node version 14 BUT in node version 20 it says RSA_PKCS1_PADDING is no longer supported for private decryption, this can be reverted with --security-revert=CVE-2023-46809
I don't want to use security-revert=CVE-2023-46809
Besides I have to use RSA PKCS1 PADDING algorithm with PKCS1 padding algorithm
Thanks in advance
const crypto = require('crypto');

encrypt(data) {
   const signerObject = crypto.publicEncrypt(
      { key: this.pubKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING },
      Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data))
   );
   return signerObject.toString('base64');
 } 


 decrypt(data) {
    const decrypted = crypto
        .privateDecrypt({ key: this.privKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING },  Buffer.from(data, 'base64'))
      .toString();
    return JSON.parse(decrypted);
  }

Please propose solution for node version 20

What specific version of Node.js are you running? Wouldn't it be easier to upgrade Node itself to at least v20.11.1, which has a patch for the CVE in question?

I have node v20.10.0 installed on my localhost and the decryption is working good. However when I upload my project on vercel.com, I'm getting the following RSA_PKCS1_PADDING Is No Longer Supported... error

@esqew I'm seeing in the link you provided that PKCS#1 padding for privateDecrypt was disabled. Do you know whats the alternative or workaround? This is since I used RSA_PKCS1_PADDING for encryption in a lot of my systems

@D.Rattansingh  , Can you please post an answer with solution. It will help me. Thanks in advance

@esqew, Can you please post an answer with solution. It will help me. Thanks in advance

@kasfik I didn't find a solution as yet. Did you find one?

Your encryption method doesn't need to change. Change decrypt to:
import NodeRSA from "node-rsa"


export function decryptWithPrivateKey(encryptedData){
    const keyRSA=new NodeRSA(
        process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SERVER_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'), "private", {encryptionScheme:"pkcs1"}
    )
    keyRSA.setOptions({environment:"browser"})//By default it will use the node crypto library with the CVE
    return keyRSA.decrypt(encryptedData)
}

// USE AS: const decryptedkey=decryptWithPrivateKey(encryptedData).toString('utf-8')

I used next.js code here but it should be easy to convert it to node.js
UPDATE
Node.js equivalent:
const NodeRSA=require('node-rsa');

decryptWithPrivateKey(encryptedData){
    const keyRSA=new NodeRSA(
        <your-private-key-here>, "private", {encryptionScheme:"pkcs1"}
    )
    keyRSA.setOptions({environment:"browser"})//By default it will use the node crypto library with the CVE
    return keyRSA.decrypt(encryptedData)
}

// USE AS: const decryptedkey=decryptWithPrivateKey(encryptedData).toString('utf-8')

